# Efficient Downloading methods

Tags: android, download, android-asynctask

Requirement : In an app, During the first launch it is required to download all the images and data from the remote server and store them into sdcard and local sqlite database respectively. And, in the later times, the app works locally without network connection.

So, the `HTTP` response comes in `JSON` format and it needs to be parsed and stored into the database and the after parsing `JSON` I will get the image paths which needs to be downloaded and stored into the sdcard.

Currently, I am thinking to implement this using an `AsyncTask` for respective API calls. Please let me know if there any other efficient alternatives OR if there are any sample source codes doing similar task. TIA...

Comment: What is your minSDKVersion? If it is 9 or above you might use the DownloadManager. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: Why don't you put everything in one compressed tar or zip archive so you have only one download? Or even better have it as an Expansion File hosted on the Google Play Store?

Comment: I mean, I need to fetch data from server through various API calls... and insert the values into local sqlite db and certain fields contain image paths through which images should downloaded to sdcard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it really needs to be separate files you can use the [Download Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

But I would recommend packing and compressing everything into one archive file and download that.

Maybe you can use an [Expansion File](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html)?

If you decide to use an AsyncTask be aware that depending on your targetSdkVersion (>11) and Android Version (>4.0) it might [not run multithreaded](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/8M0RTFfO7-M/JZSHiOz9bPgJ) without setting a thread pool executor.

Answer (score 1):

Android provides a service for downloading files. Try [Download Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).